# Remove object from list in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm developing tags system and I need to show similar objects by tags (ManyToMany relationship). How can I remove current opened object from QuerySet with similar objects?

Main object page:
similar objects - QuerySet [Checklist: Main object page, Checklist: Simple tasks, Checklist: nocat]

How can I remove "Checklist: Main object page" from QuerySet?

```py
class ChecklistView(DetailView):
    model = Checklist
    template_name = 'checklistapp/page_checklist.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ChecklistView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['tag_checklists'] = []

        for tag in Tags.objects.filter(checklist=self.object):
            checklists = Checklist.objects.filter(tags=tag)
            context['tag_checklists'].append({
                    'checklist': checklists
                })

        return context
```

Comment: `checklists = Checklist.objects.filter(...).exclude(pk=self.object.pk)`

Comment: So simple. Thank you! :)